# input a string into a 2d array while also adding different chars inbetween

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, output

I am trying to make a board game. I have to input a .txt file and make it almost as a grid

```
  F.F  
  ...  
.......
SSSSSSS
SSSSSSS
  SSS  
  SSS
```

And have it come out as

```
7     F-.-F
      |\|/|
6     .-.-.
      |/|\|
5 .-.-.-.-.-.-.
  |/|\|/|\|/|\|
4 S-S-S-S-S-S-S
  |/|\|/|\|/|\|
3 S-S-S-S-S-S-S
      |\|/|
2     S-S-S
      |/|\|
1     S-S-S
  a b c d e f g
```

This is somewhat what I have so far but I am just lost as in how to add the characters inbetween the inputed information

part of board.h

```
class BoardSet {
public:

    void startingBoard(std::string line, int row);
    void print();

private: 
char board[6][6];

};
```

part of board.cpp

```
void BoardSet::startingBoard(std::string line, int row)
{
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    board[row][i] = line[i];

}

}

void BoardSet::print()
{
int row = 7;

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 7;j++)
    {
        cout << board[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

}
```

Part of main.cpp

```
void initalizeBoard(istream& in, BoardSet& board)
{
string line;
int row = 0;
getline(in, line);
while(in)
{
    board.startingBoard(line, row);
    row++;
    getline(in, line);

}
board.print();


}
```

all I need is a little guidance or just a simple example and I can take it from there, I am just completely stumped and don't know what to do.

Comment: It seems that format is fixed. Use another array, say ``output_board[14][13]``, copy the input to the correspond location in the new array.

Comment: But how do I go about added the first array to the other with adding the characters inbetween?

Comment: if the input file format is fixed like the example in the post, then use a ``const int pos[7][7]`` to map the position from the ``input_board[7][7]`` to the ``output_board[13][13]``;

Answer (score 0):

```
char board[6][7];

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 7;j++)
    {
        cout << board[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

your array is 6 items and each of them 7 items deep!
but you´re looping 7 x 7?

or am i missing the point?

i can't see where you read in the txt file.

i´m not convinced about ...

```
void BoardSet::startingBoard(std::string line, int row)
{
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    board[row][i] = line[i];

}

}
```

i assume this must brake ... because you´re looping 7 times ... 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 ... and you´re only filling the first dimensionof the array

try this ...

```
        void BoardSet::setupBoard() // edit
        {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 7;j++)
            {
                board[i][j] = line[i]; ////////   board[i][j] = line[i];
            }
        }
        }

        void BoardSet::startingBoard(std::string line, int row)
        {
           for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) // 6 not 7
           {
              board[row][i] = line[i];

           }
}    

    void BoardSet::print()
    {
    int row = 7;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 7;j++)
        {
            cout << board[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: I did make a mistake with the array and should set it as `board[6][6]` so it is correct. I did include the function that reads the file. it was `void initalizeBoard(istream& in, BoardSet& board)` Thank you for the advice